# How to count only 1s in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a report to see how many vehicles need a repair over the last month and how many need a service. As shown below, if a vehicle has had a repair, it has a 1 assigned to it, otherwise, it's a 0. This is my attempt currently and it's returning both 1 and 0s which I don't want. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Table]

```
 select 
   vehicles_inspections.Vehicle_ID, 
   make, 
   model, 
   count(Repair), 
   count(Service) 
 from vehicles_inspections, vehicles 
 where vehicles.Vehicle_ID = vehicles_inspections.Vehicle_ID  
 group by Vehicle_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

With the data you have shown, you can simply use `sum()` rather than `count()`:

```
select vi.Vehicle_ID, v.make, v.model, sum(vi.Repair), sum(vi.Service)
from vehicles v join
     vehicles_inspections vi
     on v.Vehicle_ID = vi.Vehicle_ID 
group by vi.Vehicle_ID, v.make, v.model;
```

This works because the values appears to be either `0` or `1`.  In other words, these columns are designed as flags that can be summed up for this purpose.

If they could take on other values, you would use something like:

```
sum(case when repair = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as repairs
```

Notes:

- You should qualify *all* column names.  I'm guessing where the columns are coming from.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Hey man that works perfect thank you, just wondering why should i never use commas i only started using sql recently i have never herd of not using them ??

Comment: @leonHill . . . They are archaic, out-dated syntax -- and have been for *decades*.  The proper syntax is explicit `JOIN`s.  It is more powerful and standard (the two main reasons).  Plus, almost everyone finds it easier to follow queries where the join conditions are with the table references, rather than mixed into the `WHERE` clause.  And if you are learning SQL, learning `JOIN` for "join" makes much more sense then learning "*comma*" for "join".

Comment: Thanks so much man, I will start to use joins now instead of commas. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

This is your existing where clause:

```
where vehicles.Vehicle_ID = vehicles_inspections.Vehicle_ID
```

To that clause, add this:

```
and repair_service_complete = 0
and repair = 1
```

or whatever similar filter achieves your business requirement.